# Using Silverlight User Controls and Styles from separate Project

Tags: silverlight

I have a 2 silverlight projects

- Dashboard (the main app)
- Dashboard.Controls (user controls)

I have a UserControl in Dashboard.Controls called header which has a grid that references a style

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource HeaderBackground}" Height="55">...</Grid>
```

I had declared this style in the Dashboard App.xaml (via a resource dictionary) but this isn;t visible to the control.

My question is where do I create the ResourceDictionary that holds HeaderBAckground so it is accessible to the UserControl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say that you have a "style" in your App.xaml, but looking at the code you have pasted the Grid will be looking for a Brush. If it is indeed a Style that you want to reference, you should change the xaml to:

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource HeaderBackground}" Height="55">...</Grid>
```

Apart from that, what you are trying to do should work. Post more info if this does not help.

Comment: Perfect - My propblem was I was trying to set Bakcground rather than Style!

Thanks.